# How to make two authors use the same affiliation

Tags: formatting, acm, author, affiliation, acmart

I am using [ACM 2017](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) conference template. I have the first author have two affiliations, one of them is shared with the third author. I am running short of space and want to reduce space. I want to use a format that allows me add superscript to the authors names, and write each institution once. I want it to look similar to this picture (see the last author where it has two affiliations one of them is shared with another author, so I want to write the shared affiliation once).

[image]

My ACM template looks like this:

[image]

where I do not like the repeated affiliations in the first and third author. Can you help me modify it to make it look like the picture above?

Sample latex code:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array, makecell} 

\author{First Author}
\affiliation{%
    \institution{First Instit.}
    \city{First City}
    \state{First Country}
}

\affiliation{%
    \institution{Second Instit.}
    \city{Second City}
    \state{Second Country}
}
\email{first.author@first.instit}

\author{Second Author}
\affiliation{%
    \institution{Third Instit.}
    \city{Third City}
    \state{third Country}
}
\email{second.author@third.instit}

\author{Third Author}
\affiliation{%
    \institution{First Instit.}
    \city{First City}
    \state{First Country}
}
\email{third.author@third.instit}

\begin{document}

    \title{Title}

    \begin{abstract}
        Abstract  
    \end{abstract}

    \maketitle

    \section{This is a Section} Some text here.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `authblk` package, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{FamilyGAN: learning to generate images of Quahog, Rhode Island, USA}

\author[1]{Peter Griffin}
\author[1]{Cleveland Brown}
\author[2]{Glenn Quagmire}
\author[1,2,3]{Joe Swanson}

\affil[1]{School of Computing, University of Utah, Salt Lake City, UT, USA \authorcr
  \{\tt peter, cleveland, joe\}@utah.edu}
\affil[2]{NVIDIA Research, Santa Clara, CA, USA \authorcr
  \{\tt glenn, joe\}@nvidia.com}
\affil[3]{Department of Engineering, Harvey Mudd College, Claremont, CA, USA \authorcr
  \tt joe@hmc.edu}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```